# How to pass JavaScript / JQuery variable to <TD>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I am trying to get the value of JavaScript/JQuery variable and store it in table TD value but didn't succeed...

Tried So Far...

```
$("#someID").text(varNAME) / html(varNAME);

document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML = varNAME; 

document.querySelector("#someID").onclick=function() {
    document.querySelector('#someOtherID').textContent = document.getElementById('some_other_ID').value;
}
```

my code ---

```
<td id="userName"></td>
```

JS variable--

```
var assign_user123 = MyApp.optionvalue123;
    alert(assign_user123);  /*i get value in alert box*/
```

MyApp is global function and optionvalue123 is coming from other function

EDIT ----

from this, I am fetching username

```
<select title="" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" onchange="getValue(this)">
    <option value="">Select User to Assign</option>
    <?php foreach ($user as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->first_name . ' ' . $row->last_name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

JavaScript Function---

```
 var MyApp = {};

function getValue(sel) {
    MyApp.optionvalue2 = sel.value;

    var optionvalue = sel.value;
    alert(optionvalue);

    MyApp.optionvalue123 = (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
    alert(optionvalue123);       
}
```

The button on which following JS function is calling...

```
<button name="leads" id="leads" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="user_leads('passing some parameters for ajax'); "> Assign </button>

function user_leads('some_parameters to call in ajax') {

    var assign_user = MyApp.optionvalue2;
    alert(assign_user);  /*i get value in alert box...*/

    var assign_user123 = MyApp.optionvalue123;
    alert(assign_user123);  /*i get value in alert box...*/

    Didn't work /*$('#userName').html(assign_user123);*/

    Didn't work /* $('#userName').text($('#user').text(assign_user123));*/

    Didn't work /* $('#userName').text(assign_user123);*/

    Didn't work //document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = assign_user123;

    $.ajax({
        /*Some Ajax function to post data*/
    });
}
```

And in the console, there is no error or warning...

Comment: Do you need this => `document.querySelector('#userName').textContent = assign_user123`

Comment: in jquery `$('#userName').text(assign_user123)`

Comment: i tried but didn't worked

Comment: Are you considering handling asynchronous call as your variable is getting updated from a different function? If the function is not getting data from network, then you might want to have a re-look at the flow of code execution.

Comment: Do you even have a value stored in assign_user123 ? Maybe it's null .. :)

Comment: no i have value in it @noa-dev

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], the basics of what you have *should* work. By reproducing the problem to the its smallest version you make it easier to debug for everybody. A couple of things to check `UserName` **must** be unique. Also what do you get in the console with `console.log($('#userName'));` and `console.log($('#userName').length);` ? That should tell you if you've found your target and if the id is unique.

Comment: it shows length = 1 in console @JonP and id is unique

Comment: Does `$('#userName').html("Bob");` work in populating the element? After `$('#userName').text(assign_user123)` what does `console.log($('#userName').text())`  give you? What does inspecting the `userName` element with browser tools give you? Are there any CSS styles hiding or obfuscating the content? Again, an [MCVE] will help us stop guessing and give us more to work with.

Comment: $('#userName').html("Bob"); is didn't show any this but when  i try console.log($('#userName')); it shows this (" n.fn.init [p#userName, context: document, selector: "#userName"]   in this it shows --> 0:p#userName , context:document, length:1, selector:"#userName", __proto__:Object(0) ") and in 0:p#userName it shows this  --> hidden:false,id:"userName", innerHTML:"↵, innerText:"↵"   @JonP

Comment: I guessed as much as I can, for the third and final time I will as you to please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.querySelector('#someOtherID').textContent = document.getElementById('some_other_ID').value;
> ```

Firstly JS hasn't historically had assignable properties (except raw values). And the method you want is `text()`.

Try

```
$('#someOtherID').text("new value");
```

(Using jQuery's shortcut for CSS selectors.)

For the value being assigned

> document.getElementById('some_other_ID').value

Unless `#some_other_ID` is an input element (which has a `value` property) you'll need to use `text()` again (without a parameter it returns the current text content):

```
 $('#someOtherID').text($('#some_other_ID').text());
```

Comment: @user9972185 Was editing having seen your comment on the Q

Comment: @user9972185 "It didn't work" is not helpful. Please add to the question the new code you tried, and what happened (eg. error message). Does using the debugger of your browser stepping through the code show you anything? (For the latter putting intermediate values into local variables can help.)

Answer (score 0):

you can edit innerHTML of td like

```
$('#userName').html(assign_user123);
```